# Allow HTTP (ClearText) from an IP address | Flutter 2 | Android

Tags: android, flutter

I need to get a JSON response from an IP address (No Domain Name connected), but flutter 2.0 doesn't allow HTTP, so I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/8702713) to enable it, but the problem I face is I dont have domain name, to replace here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">api.example.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

I tried replacing with IP but it throws error that IP is not recognised as domain name.

`<domain includeSubdomains="true">x.x.x.x</domain>  #doesn't work`

Any solution to allow HTTP traffic from IP address.

PS: I know its unsafe.

EDIT:

I tried this methods:

1. Setting `res/xml/network_security_config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

Doesn't work.

2. Setting `res/xml/network_security_config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">65.0.XX.136</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Doesn't Work.

3. Setting `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in application tag of AndroidManifest.xml.

Doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide your code and IP address? I've worked with some similar to your case and no problems.

Comment: Try without the network security config file.

Comment: @blackapps Without network config file it was not working, thats why I had to search google and came to know that flutter 2 doesn't allow cleartext connections by default.

Comment: @ΟυιλιαμΑρκευα I edited my question with code I used, I can show you real IP in chat or something, but I dont know how to start a chat.

Comment: `that flutter 2 doesn't allow cleartext connections by default. ` Think that flutter does not mind. Its the Android OS on your device that minds. And so your app has to request using clear text traffic.

Comment: Strange. For a lot of apps i use android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"  and that is always enough. Never needed that file. Well..no Flutter.

Comment: @blackapps Before upgrading to flutter 2, all my apps were running fine on cleartext traffic on my Android 10 phone. After upgrading to flutter 2.0.0 two days ago, this issue is coming.

Comment: I wonder why Flutter minds.